# Cannot start debugging xamarin.android for a project in vs2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have a Xamarin.Android project that I haven't touched for a few months. Today when I open it, the Debug button is showing `Start` instead of the emulators that I installed. If I press `Start`button then I received `Error: Cancelled` in the output window.

[image: Device Not showing]

From another branch I can see the button showing devices correctly and I can start the project in the emulator.
[image: Device showing correctly]

I cannot figure out why. Both soluitons compile correctly. It's just one of them cannot be debugged.

Edit: I compared everything in both branches. There's no difference. Then I tried plugging in a physical android device. After enabling USB debugging on the device, the <kbd>Start</kbd> button gets refreshed and is showing the device name of the newly plugged in device along with all the other emulators. But that only last until the next restart of Visual Studio, then it returns to a simple <kbd>Start</kbd> button without listing devices.

Another observation: In `Android Manifest` of the project property, it shows `No AndroidManifest.xml found. Click to add one.` Clicking it does not do anything. And I'm pretty sure AndroidManifest.xml is right where it should be.
[image]

Another observation: If I created a new Android project, sometimes everything will be normal. Android Manifest is showing correctly and debug button is showing devices but last only until next startup of VS2019. I tried reparing VS2019 then restart computer. Also it works until next startup.

Another observation:
One of the VS2019 suddenly loads Android Manifest and devices normally after leaving open for a while. I'll see if all instances will be normal if left open long enough.

I'm using Visual Studio 16.11.4

Comment: You should compare the AndroidPlayground.csproj, to see what changed between one file and the other

Comment: They're the same sadly. I compared the whole branch.

Comment: And what if you compare the solutions? Comparing the Solutions Configurations. It happened to me with UWP, my platform configuration was set to "ARM", and I had to change it to "x86". For Android I have "Any CPU" set

Comment: @JuanSturla It's set at `Any CPU` as the last screenshot shows.

Comment: This link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/510277/visual-studio-2019-cannot-find-androidmanifestxml.html) may help you.

Comment: Tried as the links suggests. Clean->Rebuild All and suceeded. No change.

Comment: This is an issue with VisualStudio, you coud report Visual Studio problem is via Visual Studio's 'Report a Problem' menu and then follow them on the developer community site.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by YanFang Wang from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-start-debugging-xamarinandroid-for-a-projec/1572614#T-N1573976

> Uninstall all those programs from control panel:
>
> - Visual Studio 2019
> - Microsoft Visual Studio Installer
> - Microsoft Visual C++ xxxx-xxxx Redistributable (x64)- xxxx
> - Microsoft Visual C++ xxxx-xxxx Redistributable (x86)- xxxx
> - Microsoft Build of OpenJDK with Hotspot xxxxx
> - Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime
> - Microsoft SQL Server 2019 LocalDB
> - Delete “Microsoft Visual Studio” folder from C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files (x86)
> - Delete all content from C:\Users\v-yanfw\AppData\Local\Temp
> - Delete regedit: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio

Then reinstall VS2019. Problem is fixed.

Previous found alternative:
Running VS2019 as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Android Device Manager, select your emulator and run it.
2. Find the simulator you just ran in the start drop-down menu and select it.
3. Right-click your Android project and select Set as Startup Project.

Comment: The start drop-down menu does not show any devices like before. It only shows `Start` and `Project debug properties` as if my startup project is a DLL library (while my startup project is the Android Application.

Comment: Have you tried the method I provided?

Comment: I tried it several times. I selected an emulator and run it. Only once, the start drop-down menu start showing list of devices and I can debug normally. It works until I restart VS2019. Then this method does not work any more.

Comment: Is this true for all your Xamarin.Android projects?Generally speaking, the third method can be used to solve

Comment: It works rather randomly. I'm 100% sure I'm setting Xamarin.Android project as Startup Project, not library projects. The problem seemingly correlates to the inability to load AndroidManifest.xml.